# Prove that $\frac{ab+cd}{da+bc}+\frac{da+bc}{ab+cd}\geqslant\frac{4(a+c)(b+d)(ac+bd)}{2(a^2c^2+b^2d^2)+3(ab+cd)(da+bc)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> The source is [this AoPS question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3007972) (unsolved). Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d>0$, show that
> \[\frac{ab+cd}{da+bc}+\frac{da+bc}{ab+cd}\geqslant\frac{4(a+c)(b+d)(ac+bd)}{2(a^2c^2+b^2d^2)+3(ab+cd)(da+bc)}.\]

If we use AM-GM with
\[2(a^2c^2+b^2d^2)\ge(ac+bd)^2,\]
we can express the inequality in $m=ab+cd$, $n=ac+bd$, $p=ad+bc$, but the inequality becomes false.

Aside from that, here's the result of expansion,
\begin{array}{l}
3 a c^{3} d^{4}+2 b^{2} c^{2} d^{4}-4 a b c^{2} d^{4}-4 a^{2} b c d^{4}+3 a^{3} c d^{4} \\
+2 a^{2} b^{2} d^{4}+3 b c^{4} d^{3}-4 b^{2} c^{3} d^{3}-4 a^{2} c^{3} d^{3}-8 a b^{2} c^{2} d^{3} \\
{}+{}18 a^{2} b c^{2} d^{3}-4 a^{3} c^{2} d^{3}+8 a b^{3} c d^{3}-8 a^{2} b^{2} c d^{3} \\
{}-{}4 a^{3} b^{2} d^{3}+3 a^{4} b d^{3}-4 a b c^{4} d^{2}+2 a^{2} c^{4} d^{2} \\
{}-{}4 b^{3} c^{3} d^{2}+18 a b^{2} c^{3} d^{2}-8 a^{2} b c^{3} d^{2}+2 b^{4} c^{2} d^{2} \\
{}-{}8 a b^{3} c^{2} d^{2}-8 a^{3} b c^{2} d^{2}+2 a^{4} c^{2} d^{2}-8 a^{2} b^{3} c d^{2} \\
{}+{}18 a^{3} b^{2} c d^{2}-4 a^{4} b c d^{2}+2 a^{2} b^{4} d^{2}-4 a^{3} b^{3} d^{2} \\
{}+{}3 b^{3} c^{4} d-4 a b^{2} c^{4} d-8 a^{2} b^{2} c^{3} d+8 a^{3} b c^{3} d \\
{}-{}4 a b^{4} c^{2} d+18 a^{2} b^{3} c^{2} d-8 a^{3} b^{2} c^{2} d-4 a^{2} b^{4} c d \\
{}-{}4 a^{4} b^{2} c d+3 a^{4} b^{3} d+2 a^{2} b^{2} c^{4}+3 a b^{4} c^{3} \\
{}-{}4 a^{2} b^{3} c^{3}-4 a^{3} b^{3} c^{2}+2 a^{4} b^{2} c^{2}+3 a^{3} b^{4} c\overset?\ge0
\end{array}
As we can see, it isn't totally in a mess, for example, $a$ and $b$ are symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the desired inequality is homogeneous, assume that $abcd = 1$.
Let $x = ab + cd, y = bc + da, z = ac + bd$. Then $x, y, z \ge 2$.
The desired inequality is written as
$$\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \ge \frac{4(x + y)z}{2(z^2-2) + 3xy}.$$

After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
$$(2x^2 + 2y^2)z^2 + (-4x^2y-4xy^2)z + 3x^3y + 3xy^3 - 4x^2 - 4y^2 \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

Using $x, y\ge 2$ and AM-GM, we have
$$3x^3y + 3xy^3 - 4x^2 - 4y^2
= (2x^3y + 2xy^3) + x^2(xy - 4) + y^2(xy - 4) \ge 4x^2y^2. \tag{2}$$

Using $2x^2+2y^2 \ge (x + y)^2$ and (2), we have
$$\mathrm{LHS}_{(1)} 
\ge (x + y)^2z^2 + (-4x^2y-4xy^2)z + 4x^2y^2 = (2xy - xz - yz)^2 \ge 0.$$

We are done.